# How does window.onbeforeunload get called?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a message whenever the user searches using any search engine's home page. I do not want to  call this function when he searches a word using the browser address bar.

Problem I am facing: This function seems to get called in random whether I am searching using the address bar or from the website. Why is this so?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    safari.extension.dispatchMessage("WebsiteSearch")
};
```

I am very new to JavaScript. I am certain I am missing something. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: um, onbeforeunload fires whenever a user navigates from the page.... There is nothing that tells you what causes it to happen.

Comment: but then there are times when it does not fire. Is this scenario I am facing related to onbeforeunload or something else in my code?

Comment: You have a Safari extension presumably (right?) - I'd use the [webextensions.webNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation) api and just listen to `onBeforeNavigate` to know when the page will unload and do whatever you need without running code in the content script bit.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is very weak, browsers may choose not to fire it for various reasons (e.g. they feel like it, no user interaction, not trusted enough etc) because various sites abuse it for spam and to trick users.

Extensions on the other hand are very strong permission wise.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum does this function get called only when the user navigates from the website links or also when the user navigates from the browser address bar?

Comment: @onetrueshady honestly I haven't done Safari WebExtension development it's quite new and I don't know. If this behaves like Chrome's - I _think_ this function will get called whenever a tab navigates (including but not limited to `search`). There is _technically_ a simpler API with the `.search` domain but I don't think safari web extensions implement it.

Comment: Also as an unrelated nit: there is really no reason to do `e || window.event` - that's an anachronism for browsers that didn't pass the event as an argument. You're better off doing `addEventListener` and not using event handlers and `e` will always be there (assuming you're not writing code for IE6 or Netscape 7 :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am getting a console error as ReferenceError: Can't find variable: browser

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions